# requirejs module and jquery with class selector

Tags: jquery, module, requirejs

Just started using requirejs and having some trouble binding a module to multiple elements with the same class name. What looks to be happening is the module is only binding once i.e to the first element.

All anchors the href alerted always shows the same value -- the first value.

**layout.html**

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/js/components/requirejs/require.js', data-main='/js/main')
```

**list.html**

The list page has several anchors all having the same class.

```
<a href='/books/1' class='view'>View Me</a>
<a href='/books/2' class='view'>View Me</a>
<a href='/books/..' class='view'>View Me</a>
<a href='/books/5' class='view'>View Me</a>

require(['page/book']);
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'components/jquery/jquery',
        domready: 'components/requirejs-domready/domReady'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'domready'], function() { });
```

**/page/book.js**

```
require(['main'], function () {
    require(['jquery', 'modules/Book'], function ($, Follow) {
        new Book($('.view'));
    });
});
```

**/modules/Book.js**

```
define(function (require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');

    var Book = function (element) {
       var anchor = $(element);
       $(document).on('click', element, function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert(anchor.attr('href'));
       })
    };

    Book.prototype = {

    };

    return Book;
});
```

How do I get it to return a different href for each anchor clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with the element related to the event itself.

Right now you have a perpetual reference to your jQuery collection `element`/`anchor` because a closure is passed along with the handler itself.

Thus when you call `anchor.attr('href')` you're always going to get the `href` of the first element in the collection.

Deal with the `event.target` instead:

```
var Book = function (element) {
   var anchor = $(element);
   $(document).on('click', element, function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var $anchor = $(e.target);
       alert($anchor.attr('href'));
   })
};
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Don't know why I didn't do something like this, I would usually do var container = $(this); to get the element. The above works also.